# Apple Mac OS X Mavericks inside Virtual Box

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

*BEGIN EDIT*

> In view of the Software License Agreement (SLA) posted by
>   MariusMatutiae, which documents the fact that Mac OS X is licensed to
>   run only on Apple-branded hardware, and can only be installed on a
>   single computer, I wonder, since the Mavericks version is free, does
>   this mean it can now be installed on any number of computers starting
>   from a single download? But more importantly, and here is what puzzles
>   me: **I have a version of VirtualBox on Windows 7 that shows the
>   option to install Mac OS X, even though Apple seems to not allow this.
>   However, I strongly doubt that my version of Oracle Virtual Box is
>   illegal, or Apple would have followed suit. Can someone please clarify THIS issue?**
>
> Please see the screenshot below, which shows Mac OS X selected for install inside
>   a Virtual Box running on Windows 7:

[image]

*END EDIT*

I have a few questions regarding Mac OS X and OS virtualization.

A.

Given all the legal restrictions imposed by Apple on Apple products,
I would like to know whether it is legal to install the new and freely
downloadable Apple Mac OS X Mavericks inside Oracle Virtual Box.

B.

What about older OS X versions such as Mountain Lion?

C.

How many machines can I install it on. What if I don't use the Mac to
which the OS is downloaded but only use it on Virtual Box, and prefer
to, say, install Linux on the Mac computer so that it doesn't become
unusable due to the single user license policy and me running the
OS on Windows 7 within Virtual Box?

D.

I have a PC running Windows 7 but would like to get the OS off a second
had Mac I'm planning to purchase for this purpose. How must we proceed
to copy the OS to an ISO so that I can install it on Windows 7?
I am unfamiliar with Macs and do not know what software to use
for the purpose, nor where the OS is downloaded to (as an ISO,
.app executable, .gz or .zip file or whatever). If anyone could
provide some guidance with the process I would sincerely appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snow Leopard SLA states verbatim:

> 2. Permitted License Uses and Restrictions.
>      A. Mac OS X Server Software. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, you are granted a limited non-exclusive license to install and
>      use one copy of the Mac OS X Server software (the “Mac OS X Server Software”) on a single Apple-branded computer. You may also install and use
>      other copies of Mac OS X Server Software on the same Apple-branded computer, provided that you acquire an individual and valid license from
>      Apple for each of these other copies of Mac OS X Server Software. You agree not to install, use or run the Apple Software on any non-Apple-
>      branded computer, or to enable others to do so. This License does not allow the Mac OS X Server Software to run on more than one computer at
>      a time, and, except as expressly set forth in Section 2C, you may not make the Apple Software available over a network where it could be run by
>      multiple computers at the same time. Please note that the Apple Software is supported only on Apple-branded systems that meet the specified
>      system requirements as indicated on the outside of the Mac OS X Server packaging. If you transfer software from one Apple-branded computer
>      to another Apple-branded computer, please remember that continued use of the original copy of the software may be prohibited once a copy has
>      been transferred to another computer, unless you already have a licensed copy of such software on both computers. You should check the
>      relevant software license agreements for applicable terms and conditions.

Other SLAs are identical, in this respect. As you see, you can only run it on Apple-branded hardware. That answers all of your questions, I believe.

Comment: OK, I've now found out why it is possible to run Mac OS X inside Virtual Box running on Windows, and Apple can't sure oracle for it. It is because that version of Windows could be running on Mac OS X, and that bottom layer Mac OS X system on Apple hardware. That's the reason! (I found my answer here: http://www.instructables.com/answers/Is-it-legal-to-run-Mac-OS-X-in-Windows-on-Virtualb/ ).

Comment: Could "Apple-branded" be satisfied by putting an Apple logo sticker on the computer?  (I'm not joking)

Comment: Yeah, probably, although I doubt Apple would every provide such a sticker.